Text console display frozen on Arch Linux after boot
My desktop PC running Arch Linux developed an issue with the text console in the last few days. The system boots OK initially, then appears to freeze just before the login prompt would normally appear (I normally boot to the text console and will use startx if I want to run X). When booting without the quiet flag, the last thing displayed is "Reached target Multi-User System." Trying to switch to other VTs using Ctrl-Alt-Fn appears to have no effect. I see the same problem in single-user mode. I also run gpm but do not see the mouse "cursor" appear when moving the mouse.
After some investigation I realised that the system is actually running and responsive, it's just that the text console is frozen. My first clue was that typing Ctrl-Alt-Del would restart the system, and I found I could log in remotely via ssh, and everything seems fine: the system is running getty on ttys 1 through 7, and gpm is running. I could even type my username and password "blind" at the machine and confirm that was logged in by running beep.
I've also found (and this might be related) that running startx once logged in no longer works. Even though my user account is a member of the tty group, I have to change the ownership on the /dev/tty* files first. X then runs normally and everything seems fine, though when I exit X the monitor gets no signal and goes into standby.
I don't believe it's a hardware problem, as I can boot into an older Debian installation on the system and it runs normally. System is a generic 64-bit Intel PC running kernel 6.11.8-arch1-2 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC. I believe the problem started after a system update.
Thanks for any troubleshooting suggestions...

I'm having the same exact issue. I'm wondering if it's the NVIDIA drivers for my 1070 or something related to systemd-homed. Did you ever resolve it?
